# angular-cli: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" when compiling for production and AOT

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, uglifyjs

I am using angular2 typescript and compiling with angular-CLI

when I try to compile with AOT and production `ng build --aot --prod`
i get an error for no reason:

```
ERROR in main.4b427a390fd79800862f.bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (UriPipe) [main.4b427a390fd79800862f.bundle.js:19,4]
```

but the code is fine.. 
and when I compile for development (without uglify) all works fine

(UriPipe is a pipe I made which works ok)

## versions:

```
os: ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Windows 10 x64
browser: chrome v56
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 6.9.4
npm: 3.10.10
typescript: 2.0.10
angular2: 2.3.1
```

Comment: Have you tried `ng serve --aot` to see the stack trace in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was in the tsconfig.json the target was set to es6 and uglifyjs works only for es5

Comment: if this answers your question, you should accept this answer please :)

Comment: I changed all the references of es2015/es6 to es5 in tsconfig.json and still no luck. do I need to change the module and lib as well or only target?

Comment: It worked. There are 2 tsconfig.json file in my project and it seems I was changing the wrong one. I update both and it worked.